# Time Series with a for loop

Tags: r

I have this equity model that generates independent 225 values of S. But i want to make it such that S[i+1] is calculated from the previous S[i] value. I have made a mess of the code, please help.

```
St <- 10
r <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.1
z <- rnorm(225) 
h <- seq(0,1,by=1/225)
t <- h[-1]

S <- numeric(225)
for (i in 1:225){
S <- St * exp( (r - 0.5 * (sigma^2)) * t + sigma * z * sqrt(t) )
S[i+1] <- S[i]* exp( (r - 0.5 * (sigma^2)) * t[i+1] + sigma * z * sqrt(t[i+1])) 
}

S
```

Comment: Please clean up your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Define `S[1]` first, then loop through `i in 1:224` and set `S[i+1]`.